# DevExpress TreeList CheckBox checked event?

Tags: c#, devexpress-windows-ui

I have a TreeList with a DataTable as datasource. One of the columns are of type bool in the DataTable and is automatically shown as a checkbox editor in the TreeList. I'm looking for an event that is fired immediately after a checkbox's checked state is changed. I'm handling the CellValueChanged event, but it fires only after the node is loses focus. I can't seem to find any event from the TreeList that will fire immediately after a checkbox is changed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your datasource? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1316417/3242721) for more.

Comment: Because the datasource is not updated until the node loses focus. It seems the editor does not post the value to the TreeList (and then the datasource) before it is closed.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I just checked myself. How about trying [`CellValueChanging`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_CellValueChangingtopic)? I tried on a dX grid and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Ah, I can't believe I missed that one. Exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [`CellValueChanging`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_CellValueChangingtopic) should serve you well in this case.